# How to use kafka-python to send customized payload? (between two ubuntu machines under same WIFI network)

Tags: python, apache-kafka

How to use kafka-python to send customized payload?

I have "two ubuntu machines", and both are under same WIFI network(one address is 172.20.10.2, the other is 172.20.10.7), I can use deepstream test4 python script successfully transmit the detected bounding box info through kafka by use the above ip. But I want the customized payload...
Thus, I tried some kafka-python scrpit.
For producer:

```
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['172.20.10.7:9092'])
for e in range(100):
    data = {'number' : e}
    producer.send('demo01', value=data)
    sleep(1)
```

For consumer:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from json import loads

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'demo01',
     bootstrap_servers=['172.20.10.7:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='my-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

for message in consumer:
    print(message.value)
```

did not work... So need some suggestion or the executable code if possible!

Comment: I think you need to encode, serialise producer message value before producing and after consuming you need to decode, deserialise consumer message value. refer [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-kafka-in-python-604b3250aa05)

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the producer data as JSON if you want to `json.loads` it

```
producer.send('demo01', value=json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I just followed your comments, it did not show error message, but did not get anything from consumer...

Comment: Oh, I think I resolve it... by adding a time.sleep() in the sending loop. But I have no idea why...

Comment: @EdwardChang Because producers do not immediately send unless you `.flush()` the producer (ideally, after the loop rather than each iteration)